# UI-Router: sequential resolve of parent and child states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-routing

I have two **abstract** states `parent` and `parent.child`, and an activateable state `parent.child.grand`.

I want `parent` to be **promise resolved** before `parent.child.grand` gets its resolves executed. Why? Because a certain data which comes from the ajax request in the resolve from `parent` is required in`parent.grand.child`.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/srph/039124ab9a8c67e9a538)

Is it possible to **sequentially** chain the promises of parent to children states without using controllers ?

(`parent` resolve start -> finish ajax request -> resolve promise -> `parent.child.grand` resolve start -> finish ajax request -> resolve promise)

Comment: This happens by default no?

Comment: Check the edit. It seems that parent.child.grand starts its resolve even before parent has resolved its promise

Comment: Sorry this is the best I have: here's an hour long video where the inventor of Ui-Router explains the whole thing, I think he mentions how to deal with this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqJRoh8MnBo

Comment: I'll take a look. Do you have an idea on which timeframe(mm:ss) it is?

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat No luck

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've seen a few answers for this but it still wasn't entirely clear without an example. The docs say:

> The resolve keys MUST be injected into the child states if you want to
>   wait for the promises to be resolved before instantiating the
>   children.

**Here's the example:**

```
    $stateProvider.state('parent', {
          resolve:{
             resA:  function(){
                return {'value': 'A'};
             }
          },
          controller: 'parentCtrl'
       })
       .state('parent.child', {
          resolve:{
             // Adding resA as an argument here makes it so that this child state's resB resolve
             // function is not run until the parent state's resA resolve function is completed.
             resB: function(resA){
                return {'value': resA.value + 'B'};
             }
          }
          controller: 'childCtrl'
        })
```

And you don't have to inject resA into the child controller.

Comment: Is there no way to force this behavior? I have a lot of child states that inherit from root state and would like all of them to wait until root is resolved.

Answer (score 6):

If you add `auth` to the dependency injection of your grandchild resolve, ui-router will resolve it prior to the grandchild resolve.

`['authsrv', 'auth', function(authsrv, auth){}]`

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'll check again. It was working for no reason, which I thought was a bug or some luck. How about for sibling resolves? Will the same method allow me to order the priorities?

Comment: The resolve chain only works for child/grand child etc. You aren't able to inject a resolve from another tree. Also the resolves are all run async but if you inject another resolve that one(or multiple) will be resolved prior to the one you inject it to. It may have been working before due to sheer luck of when each resolve was completing. You could have it work 100 times and then fail once. I'm probably doing a terrible job of explaining how it works but when I'm back in front of a computer I think there is a page in the ui-router docs that explains it.

Comment: What do you mean by resolve from another tree? By sibling resolves, I meant: grandResolveA start -> grandResolveA finish -> grandResolveB start -> grandResolveB finish.