# How to sequentially execute resolve for parent's route and then for children routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

Here is my simplified routes for angular2 project:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: "user/:user_id",
    component: UserAuthComponent,
    resolve: {
      _auth: UserAuthResolver
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: UserComponent,
        resolve: {
          user: UserResolver
        }
      },
      // .... many more routes that require authentication cookie 
    ]
  }
]
```

where `UserAuthResolver` makes `GET` request to server to set authentication cookie (which is required for `UserResolver` as well as all children routes resolver (not shown here) to succeed).

But it seems that angular2 doesn't sequentially execute the `resolve` in parent route and `resolve` in `children` routes but instead, it races all the 'relevant' `resolve`. Therefore, very often, the above code will alert authentication errors.

Is there a way to work around this?

FYI, I cannot put `UserAuthResolver`, say, inside `UserComponent` because then, it means duplicating the 'authentication' code all over the places where it is required.

---

Edit: This thing is apprently called, `nested resolve`. In short, how do I deal with nested resolve in angular2? In Angular1, it seemed [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333092/ui-router-sequential-resolve-of-parent-and-child-states).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364815/angular-2-nested-routes-resolve-execution) seems related, but no answer is given...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this was a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12148) and is [fixed](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12032) in new **2.1.0** release.

I've confirmed that this release indeed solves the issue.